# Problema con hacer conteos por grupos en Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Tengo una tabla con muchos registros desde el día 01 del mes Junio del año 2020 hasta el día 15 de Junio del 2021, por cada minuto de la hora del día, hay n cantidad de registros, necesito saber cuantos registros hay por minuto. Con el siguiente código, puedo hacer el conteo pero de un minuto en especifico:

```
select count(tablasmol.fecha) from tablasmol as tablasmol 
--toma la parte del año (2020)
where date_part('year', tablasmol.fecha) = 2020 
--toma la parte del mes(6 Junio)
and date_part('month',tablasmol.fecha) = 6
--toma la parte del día
and date_part('day', tablasmol.fecha) = 02 
--toma la parte de la hora (16 horas)
and date_part('hour',tablasmol.fecha) = 16
--toma la parte de los minutos (55 minutos)
and date_part('minute', tablasmol.fecha) = 15
```

Necesito hacer eso mismo, pero con todos los minutos que hay en la tabla, estuve intentando hacerlo de esta manera:

```
do $$
declare  iMinuto int := 0;
         iHora int := 0;
         iDia int := 1;
         iMes int := 1;
         iAño int := 2020;
        
         totalMinuto int := 59;
         totalHora int := 23;
         totalDia int := 28;
         totalMes int := 12;
         totalAño int := 2021;
begin       
    select count(tablasmol.fecha) from tablasmol as tablasmol
    where tablasmol.fecha notnull 
    for iAño in 1..totalAño
    loop 
        and date_part('year', tablasmol.fecha) = iAño 
        for iMes in 1..totalMes
        loop 
            and date_part('month', tablasmol.fecha) = iMes 
            for iDia in 1..totalDia
            loop 
                and date_part('day', tablasmol.fecha) = iDia
                for iHora in 1..totalHora
                loop 
                    and date_part('hour', tablasmol.fecha) = iHora
                    for iMinuto in 1..totalMinuto
                    loop 
                        and date_part('minute', tablasmol.fecha) = iMinuto
                        Raise notice 'Hay un total de: %',iMinuto;
                    end loop;
                end loop;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end loop;

end $$;
```

Pero no funciona, ¿Saben si se puede hacer algo así cómo lo que estoy intentando? o ¿Saben cómo puedo hacerlo de una mejor manera? Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Hola, puedes decir si las respuestas te fueron útiles  gracias

Comment: @Japv Si amigo, me fueron de gran utilidad, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza la misma función para extraer los segmentos de una fecha y luego agrupar por esos segmentos, por ejemplo:

```
select   date_part('year', tablasmol.fecha) anio
       , date_part('month',tablasmol.fecha) mes
       , date_part('day', tablasmol.fecha) dia
       , date_part('hour',tablasmol.fecha) hora
       , date_part('minute', tablasmol.fecha) minuto
       , count(1) ContadorRegistros
  from tablasmol
 group by date_part('year', tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('month',tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('day', tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('hour',tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('minute', tablasmol.fecha)
 order by date_part('year', tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('month',tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('day', tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('hour',tablasmol.fecha) 
       , date_part('minute', tablasmol.fecha)
```

Esto te dará la cantidad de registros por cada minuto para el que tengas historia en la tabla.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la **cláusula** **group by** junto con la **función de agregación** **count**. En esta consulta se contarán todos los registros cuya fecha sea la misma. Esta consulta te funcionará si descartas los segundos de la fecha:

```
select fecha, count(fecha) as Total
from tabla
group by fecha;
```

O bien podrías usar esta otra que descarta los segundos de la fecha:

```
select date_trunc('minute', fecha) as Fecha, count(*) as Total
from tabla
group by date_trunc('minute', fecha);
```

En esta última consulta se agruparán y contarán los registros que tengan el mismo año, mes, día, hora y minuto. Se emplea la **función** **date_trunc**, la cual en este caso obtiene una fecha con un grado de precisión hasta los minutos.

Comment: Ya probé, la primera opción me funciona, pero me toma los segundos, necesito que haga lo mismo, pero sin que tome los segundos y la segunda opción no me funciona

Comment: Que error te da en la segunda opción?

Comment: @LuisMartinez, revisa lo nuevo que puse